# I need to run a shell command after connecting with SSHFS

Tags: shell, scp, sshfs

I'm connecting to a remote server using SSH. Unfortunately, a connection with Nautilus or Konqueror over SCP did not work (although it perfectly works fine over SSH). I am not using SSHFS which works fine.

The problem is that after connecting to my server, I need to run 'sudo -s' to get access to all files (the user has root user privileges).

Is there any way to tell SSHFS to run this command after connecting?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. SSHFS is using SFTP subsystem, which has a command defined in the server configuration.